# How do we insert "data from more than one records", from one table to another?

Tags: mysql, sql

Following command is used to insert data from one table into another.

```
insert into school_record (phone_id)
    select phone_id from students where name="abc"
    order by phone_id asc;
```

But what if I want to insert all the phone_id values for the names "abc", "def", "ghi" and so on...

That is how to insert data from one table to another table, after selecting values from more than one records?

Comment: Use `IN()` like `where name IN('abc','def' ....)`

Comment: Zarah you should read last para @ [13.2.5.1 INSERT ... SELECT Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-select.html) "order by" may matters even if single column. Read the example of "replication"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use IN() - in brackets list all names which you need to insert

```
insert into school_record (phone_id)
select phone_id 
from students 
where name in ('abc', 'def', 'ghi', ...)
;
```

Or if you need to insert all

```
insert into school_record (phone_id)
select phone_id 
from students 
;
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want all the phone_ids of the students table you can simply do:

```
insert into school_record (phone_id) select phone_id from students  order by phone_id asc;
```

Answer (score 2):

Only your WHERE clause limits the number of records. Make it

```
where Name = 'abc' or name = 'def' or name = 'ghi'
```

or

```
where name in ('abc','def','ghi')
```

Comment: BTW: The ORDER BY clause should not be necessary. You should see table data as an unordered set. You would order it only in a select statement by one or more of its columns.

Comment: No, here select is with insert, Select don't have any guaranty to return same order in different executions, If you store results that ordering may matters (may be not example Zarah asked but in some complicate database). So order by inportant even if single column

Comment: @Grijesh Chauhan: I don't understand. This is an insert statement, so it simply adds records to the set of records in the table. So the order by is *not* necessary. (The order by would make a difference if there were an auto incremented ID. But still, I wouldn't consider it a good idea to thus give the ID a meaning beyond referencing its record.)

Comment: Ah, okay, I didn't know about the replication strategy in MySQL. So, when using replication there is another possible reason for using an order by in an insert-select in MySQL. (Though the only issue with not using order by I can think of right now is auto-incremented IDs, which is said to be no problem here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/replication-features-auto-increment.html. So I wonder what other issues there could be.)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to insert data with constant name then you can try below:

```
insert into school_record (phone_id)
    select phone_id from students where name in ("abc","def","xyz")
    order by phone_id asc;
```

if you want to insert phone_id for the name that contain by some another table then try below:

```
insert into school_record (phone_id)
    select phone_id from students where name in (select name from tablename)
    order by phone_id asc;
```

refer "in" from below:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_in